# How are tag badge points earned?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

To be specific the users which have bronze, silver, golden tags on specific tag/subject, how they earn points?

Like per accepted answer = 1 point?

Per upvoted answer = 1 point?

Per 10/15 rep on answer = 1 point?

Apologies if it is duplicate or if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag badge is based upon your *total score* on answers in the tag. That is, all the upvotes, minus the downvotes. Questions and Community Wiki answers don't count. It also doesn't matter if the answer is accepted or not.

You can see the score by hovering over the tag on your profile page, it is displayed in the tooltip.

There is some delay due to caching; if you have just gained (or lost) points in a tag, it will not immediately be reflected in the tooltip.

Comment: like if i answered 5 question with 3 upvote and 2 downvote each, my score will be 1 on that tag.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Yes. Another example, if you answered 3 questions, one had 3 upvotes (+3), one had a downvote (-1), another had an upvote and a downvote (+1/-1), your score would be 3 - 1 + 1 -1 = 2.